# How to fix React Native RTCView Error: Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view

The Error is: Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! (Trying to add a '[RTCVirtualText 735]' to a '[RCTView 737]').

```
<View style={{flex:0.6,marginTop:"10%",alignItems:"center"}}>
          <Text>Don't have an account? <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => navigation.navigate("Sign Up") }><Text style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>Sign up!</Text></TouchableOpacity></Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trouble shooting - the TouchableOpacity component being inside a Text component was causing the error. Not sure why.